# Symfony Services: Is there a way to set a public property in `services.yml`?

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, browscap

Is there a way to set a public variable by means of the service definition in  `services.yml`?

The reason is, that i am using the [phpbrowscap library](https://github.com/GaretJax/phpbrowscap). To use a local file for resolving the browser i need use this line of code:

```
$this->browscap->localFile = "..."
```

> unfortunately this poor property is public and does not have a setter. it's neither available in constructor.

so how would i set this property in `services.yml`? is that even possible to achieve?

this is the part in my `services.yml`:

```
browscap:
        class: Browscap
        arguments:
            - %browscap_cache_dir%
```

if there was a setter i would add `call`there... but well...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried using the `property injection` method of the DI-Container?

https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/injection_types.html#property-injection

```
app.newsletter_manager:
     class: AppBundle\Mail\NewsletterManager
     properties:
         mailer: '@mailer'
```

Comment: If this solved your problem please consider accepting the answer.

Comment: sorry, forgot that

Answer (score 2):

You can use Factory to configure instance of service:

```
services:
    # ...

    browscap:
        factory:   'AppBundle\Service\BrowscapStaticFactory:createBrowscap'
        arguments: ['%browscap_cache_dir%']
```

Factory class:

```
class BrowscapStaticFactory
{
    public static function createBrowscap($cacheDir)
    {
        $browscap = new Browscap();
        $browscap->localFile = $cacheDir;

        // ...

        return $browscap;
    }
}
```